# Blue Yeti microphone not allowed as duplex

Tags: sound, microphone

Running Ubuntu 20.04. I have a Blue Yeti microphone which I used to plug my headphones into the audio jack and have it to passthrough audio from my laptop to it.

Used to work flawlessly until a few weeks ago, but now I can no longer select Yeti as both input and output. When I do, the other one switches to something else I have plugged in for that direction.

I installed `pavucontrol` and I noticed that, in Configuration, the only profiles available for Yeti are analog/digital input or output, but no duplex. Looking for answers I saw other people's screenshots where their Yeti also had profiles like "Digital Stereo Duplex."

What am I missing? I don't think the Yeti has any driver or whatever I can update. I also don't really know what changed because I haven't used this mic for a month while I was away from home but still using the same laptop.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `dmesg` when you plug in the microphone?  It may give others some ideas and insight.

Comment: Sure, will add to the post.

Comment: Oh wow, that actually showed me the answer with another detail I didn't tell in my post...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** (kinda) - Another detail I totally missed: I use a 4x2 USB KVM to plug peripherals and switch between work and personal computers. Turns out that `dmsg` as suggested by in the comment told me what was wrong:

```
[ 9357.574920] usb 3-4.1: new full-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
[ 9357.701873] usb 3-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=b58e, idProduct=0005, bcdDevice= 4.06
[ 9357.701884] usb 3-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 9357.701887] usb 3-4.1: Product: Yeti Nano
[ 9357.701889] usb 3-4.1: Manufacturer: Blue Microphones
[ 9357.701892] usb 3-4.1: SerialNumber: 2053SG008DC8_888-000162040606
[ 9357.729764] input: Blue Microphones Yeti Nano Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1:1.3/0003:B58E:0005.0048/input/input129
[ 9357.787043] input: Blue Microphones Yeti Nano as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1:1.3/0003:B58E:0005.0048/input/input130
[ 9357.787385] hid-generic 0003:B58E:0005.0048: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Blue Microphones Yeti Nano] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.1/input3
[ 9358.489167] usb 3-4.1: Not enough bandwidth for new device state.
[ 9358.489180] usb 3-4.1: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 1
[ 9358.489184] usb 3-4.1: 2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-28)
[ 9358.490096] usb 3-4.1: Not enough bandwidth for new device state.
[ 9358.490111] usb 3-4.1: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 1
[ 9358.490115] usb 3-4.1: 2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-28)
```

The "what changed" is a new keyboard that I now have to plug yet another dongle to the KVM. I used to have a Logitech Unifying receiver (mouse+keyboard), a webcam and the mic. The new keyboard uses the new Logibolt dongle, so the KVM is now full. But apparently, the KVM can't handle all the devices together + duplex for the mic. It makes sense since it's cramming 4 USB signals into one.

If I unplug the keyboard dongle, the mic can now be duplex (the duplex profile even shows up in `pavucontrol`). Weirdly though, unplugging one of the other 2 devices won't work, but unplugging both (leaving only the keyboard + mic) works! This Logibolt probably uses much more bandwidth than the other two.